# Motorola Scanner SDK VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, barcode-scanner, motorola

I have looked for the last couple days for any examples of using the Motorola SDK for VB.NET in a Windows Application and can't find anything.

I am trying to fire an event when the scanner is used which then reads the barcode that has been scanned and if it doesn't match to a value I was expecting it will make the scanner beep and the Red LED come on.

I am using a LI4278 scanner which is handheld with a cradle so I know the scanner Id will need to be set to 2.

Any information or point me to somewhere I haven't looked would be excellent.

Many Thanks

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Have you tried something?
The Motorola .net API was quite good and they delivered a complete demo application. If you have a concrete question, I think I could help you, I've already integrated this scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation from Motorola (both the Developer Guide and the Attribute Definitions) which can be found by Googling "Motorola Scanner SDK."

As for the cradle, I wrote a loop into the code that kept searching for scanners until it found two as my cradle would always show up but the actual scanner was not as cooperative.

I can't help you with the conversion from C# to VB but those guides I mentioned have a lot of useful information and the language differences should be relatively easy to get around.